# Getting a command line string inside an object

Tags: python, proxy

I'm trying to create a proxy/manager pair for a class and am totally stuck on how to proxy intances of objects that exist within that class.

Is there anyway the proxy could find out the string of the command that called it (or even better a list of arguments and keywords)?

For those who want more details the following is a simple demonstration:

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        if name == 'main' : self.inside=test('inside')
    def call(self,ans):
        return 'Hello to you too' 

t=test('main')
```

Now my understanding python is that python commands are two stage processes A call to t.call('hello') results in a pointer to t.call being returned which in this case happened to be:

```
print(t.call)
<__main__.test instance at 0x22dd908>
```

This instance is then called with the argument 'hello'

```
print(t.call('hello')
'hello to you too'
```

In a similar way :

```
print(t.inside.call('hello'))
'hello to you too'
```

In this case t.inside.**getattr** returns main.test instance at 0x208c680>> which is then called with the argument 'hello'
If you proxy t and then type t.call('hello') then what is happening is that the proxy is using pickle to pass on the string 'call' and *args to the manager which then runs the remote version of call and passes back the string 'hellow to you too' via pickle.  If you want to access an attribute via the proxy (t.name) then the proxy sends 'getatrib' and 'name' via pickle and gets back from the manager 'main' (via pickle)

The problem is if you type `t.inside.name` - as inside is an attribute the proxy sends `getatrib` and `inside` and the manager tries to pickle 'inside' to send back - which cannot be pickled so the call fails.

If the proxy could just get the complete command eg. t.inside.call('hello') on the first call to its own **getattr** then it could send this off to the manager which could return the result no problem but so far I cannot work out how to get anything other than 'inside'.

Answer (score 0):

in python, you can get the name of a command with

`function.__name__`

the module is in

`function.__module__`